# Naming Conflict in class file

Tags: java

I have two files here, Inside the StaticSuper class(file 2), there appears to be a naming clonflict on the StaticSuper Method. Why is this?

```
    public class StaticTests extends StaticSuper {
        static int rand;

        static {
            rand = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
            System.out.println("static block " + rand);
        }

        StaticTests() {
            System.out.println("constructor");
        }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            System.out.println("in main");
            StaticTests st = new StaticTests();
        }

    }  

    class StaticSuper {

        static {
            System.out.println("Super static block");
        }

    //naming conflict here
        StaticSuper{
                    System.out.println("super constructor");
                }

            }
```

Comment: Is that meant to be a constructor?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Judging by `System.out.println("super constructor");` I think we can safely assume that: yes. It looks like simple typographical problem (lack of `()` in constructor declaration).

Comment: You forgot the parentheses in the constructor declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are constructing classes incorrectly. Class constructor should be the following

```
class StaticSuper {
    public StaticSuper (){
        System.out.println("super constructor");
    }
}
```

public is optional, but the brackets should always be present. Learn a little bit [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)